# Analyzing the rates of cooling points using the graph and data

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, temperature, data-analysis, cooling

[image]

[image]

**how should i use this data to analyse the differences between the two materials. and what calculations could i use for it?**

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Both curves look like exponential decay. This means that the cooling rate is proportional to the temperature difference between your material and environment. You can fit each curve by an expression like $$T^{s,p}(t)=(T^{s,p}_0-T^{s,p}_\infty) e^{-C^{s,p}t}+T^{s,p}_\infty$$
For each of the curves you have three parameters: $T_0$, $T_\infty$, and $C$. The first parameter is an indication at how much you heated the sample, the second is the final temperature. These are not that important. The $C$ constant can give you some information about the material. The larger it is, the faster the sample cools. It is a combination of multiple factors: shape of the sample (area), specific heat, what is the container, etc.